# TIN interpolation errors and weird lines [Qgis 2.18]

Tags: qgis, dem, elevation, tin, minidump

I want to create an elevation model in EPSG 4326 from [2 shapefiles](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7UB9e-AFRivNTBnV2RUSE5kbzQ) [img0] : elevation lines [Altimetria linee Antrodoco] and elevation points [Altimetria punti Antrodoco], both obtained by the District Maps database of Lazio.
[image: img0]
However I encounter several errors and/or weird rasters as a result, depending on my Interpolation settings:

a) if I choose both Points and Lines as Input [img 1 in the link above] and set them as Structure lines and Points respectively, I get minidump error [img 2], no matters the cellsize or columns values.

b) if I choose both Points and Lines as Input [img 3], and set both of them as Points, I do not get errors, but I get alwais messy/weird lines, that do not seem to follow the elevation lines at all [img4]. This happens also with clipped shapefiles.

c) all in all, whenever I choose points or lines, as soon as I change the cellsize to get 5 (project unit is meters), the rank and columns change to 0. [img 5] Only with values inferior to 0.00x I get positive ranks and columns value [img 6], independently from the size of the layer.

Since I'm a beginner, I believe there are probably many errors and issues braided together. What is the first/main problem in my procedure?

I can't add more than two links, so I put all the images in the first gdrive folder.

Comment: I have experienced similar problems with that plugin (never really understood the problem). Try to interpolate using GRASS or SAGA from the Processing toolbox

Answer (score 1):

I have tried the same tool and it crashes in my case as well. After some Google use I found out that it crashes because the data is too complex(too many vectors). Searching for alternative solution found the [Delaunay triangulation](https://docs.qgis.org/2.6/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vector_geometry_tools/delaunaytriangulation.html) tool, which allows only one parameter per turn and it's not eactly what you are looking for.
 Your data is correct if you were wondering about it. I managed [to create your TIN](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_4rj9xJBHP9R3RBdUtzLTFkbm8) in ArcMap without any issues.